# How to convert a string to uppercase without using the toUpperCase method?

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner at java and can't get this code to work. What I have to do is convert any inputted string to uppercase without using the toUpperCase string method. This is what I have:

```
public String toUpperCase(String str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char a = str.charAt(i);
        a = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        str += Character.toString(a);
    }
return str;
}
```

Comment: Create an array with pair lowercase letter na uppercase letter from A to Z and check one by one ?

Comment: But you are using the `toUpperCase` method.

Comment: My guess is this loops forever.

Comment: @shmosel IMHO, OP means `String.toUpperCase`

Comment: im wondering if you were asked to not use the String.toUpperCase() method because they want you to implement your own code which checks and upper cases the character. using Character.toUpperCase() might be "cheating"

Comment: @SlipperySeal Then you should up-vote [Zack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41154191/5221149), because it doesn't use *any* `toUpperCase()` methods.

Comment: @Andreas done. didnt see that answer when i commented

Comment: If you need "inspiration" on implementing your own toUpperCase method, why not have a look at the Java source code? For example, for Latin characters, the toUpperCase method is found in `CharacterDataLatin1#toUpperCase()`; you can find toUpperCase() methods for other types of chars by looking for concrete implementations of the `CharacterData` class.

Comment: This basic idea is certainly workable.  The thing that makes it not work for you is that you're using the same `String` variable for input and for output.  Just use two different `String` variables and you should be able to get this working.

Answer (score 9):

You are using `str` as input, and output (so your `String` has infinite length, as you keep adding characters). And you can use `static`, because you aren't using instance state. And, you might use a `for-each` loop. Finally, add another `String`, or better a `StringBuilder` like

```
public static String toUpperCase(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Since you call `str.toCharArray()` anyway, wouldn't it be better to replace the characters in that array with their uppercase equivalent, then do `return new String(array)`?

Comment: @Andreas There's certainly more than one way to do it. Zack posted that in an answer around the time of your comment.

Answer (score 6):

There is the following way, but it doesn't consider any characters outside of English (no [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), no other language’s characters behind a-z).

```
public String toUpperCase(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
        char c = chars[i];
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
            chars[i] = (char) (c - 'a' + 'A');
        }
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am aware your school probably do not allow you to use `StringBuilder` and in case you can't use array as well. This is another primitive approach which your school may accept:

```
public static String toUpperCase(String s){
    String str = "";
    for(int x=0; x<s.length(); x++){
        char ch = s.charAt(x);
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            str += "" + (char)(ch - 32);
        else
            str += "" + ch; 
    }
    return str;
}
```

**Test:**

```
System.out.println(toUpperCase("aAbBcC"));
```

**Output:**

```
AABBCC
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be allowed to use `StringBuilder`? Besides, that code implicitly uses `StringBuilder` anyway, just the very, *very* slow way.

Comment: @Andreas With my past experience with students from various schools, so far, none of their schools uses `StringBuilder` even though `string+=` is a bad approach.

Answer (score 2):

C'mon guys, Java 8 has been out for years!

```
/**
 * Converts an all-lowercase String to
 * uppercase. Retains only spaces, any
 * other characters will be lost.
 */
public static String toUpperCase(String s) {
    int diff = 'a' - 'A'; // 32

    return s.chars()
            .filter(c -> c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c == ' ')
            .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) (c - (diff))))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: fun fact, at work we have to use java 6 for development because of the compatibility reasons.

Comment: @BlackCat I understand entirely.  I really wish Java updates were forced/seamless so we wouldn't have to deal with any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use the `toUpperCase()` method, you can use the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to get from a lower case letter to an upper case letter by subtracting 32.

> 'a' = 97, 'A' = 65
>   'b' = 98, 'B' = 66
>   ...
>   'z' = 122, 'Z' = 90

```
public static int DIFF = 'a' - 'A'; // 32

public static String toUpperCase(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf((char)(c - DIFF)));
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You are incorrectly assuming that the input string is *only* lowercase letters.

Comment: @Andreas true. Fixed.

Comment: If you can't use `toUpperCase()` *(and you're not)*, don't you think `isLowerCase()` is equally off-limit?

Comment: @Andreas Since OP didn't state any restrictions on `isLowerCase()`, no. Also the condition `ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'` that other answers use, assume the input only uses the English alphabet. `Character.isLowerCase()` works for UTF-16.

Comment: True, but your code doesn't work for UTF-16. `toUpperCase("ā")` returns `á`, because uppercase letters are not always 32 code points before their lowercase equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
public static String toUpperCase(String str) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int v = str.charAt(i);
            if (v > 96 && v < 123) {
                v -= 32;
            }
            result+=(char)v;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public String toUpper(String str){

String strUp = "";
for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    char a = str.charAt(i);
    strUp += Character.toUpperCase(a);
}
return strUp;
}
```